# Can the UNIX command tree display only directories matching a pattern?

Tags: shell, command-line, tree

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get the UNIX command `tree` to display only directories that match a specific pattern.

```
% tree -d tstdir -P '*qm*' -L 1
tstdir
|-- d1
|-- d2
|-- qm1
|-- qm2
`-- qm3

5 directories
```

The **man page** shows this bit about the switch.

> -P pattern
>                 List only those files that match the wild-card pattern.  Note: you must use the -a option to also consider those files
>   beginning with a dot `.' for
>                 matching.  Valid wildcard operators are`*' (any zero or more characters), `?' (any single character),`[...]' (any single
>   character listed between
>                 brackets (optional - (dash) for character range may be used: ex: [A-Z]), and `[^...]' (any single character not listed in
>   brackets) and`|'  sepa‐
>                 rates alternate patterns.

I'm assuming that the bit about **...List only those files...** is the issue. Am I correct in my interpretation that this switch will only pattern match on files and **NOT** directories?

**EDIT #1**

[@f-hauri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1765658/f-hauri) looks to have the best reason as to why this doesn't work the way one would think from the switches available in the `tree` man page. I missed this bit in the BUGS section.

```
BUGS
   Tree  does not prune "empty" directories when the -P and -I options are
   used.  Tree prints directories as it comes to them, so  cannot  accumu‐
   late  information  on files and directories beneath the directory it is
   printing.
```

Given this limitation it looks like `tree` isn't the best way to accomplish an inclusive filtered list, but a exclusive filtered list would be an alternative way using the `-I` switch.

In lieu of this it would look like either shell wildcards, the find command, or a Perl script would be a more appropriate way to accomplish this. See [@f-hauri's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1765658/f-hauri) fine answer for some of these alternative methods.

Comment: It needs to show the directories so that when it shows a matching file you can see the rest of the tree leading to that file.

Comment: Makes sense, just wondering if there was a way to not show them.

Comment: If you're using `-L 1`, why not just do `ls tstdir/*qm*`?

Comment: If you're not relying on the format of the output, `find tstdir -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*qm*'` should work. If you don't want to see the parent directories, just the children on that level, `find tstdir -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*qm*' |sed -e 's#tstdir/##'` is a quick and dirty way to handle it. :D

Comment: In **this** case, if from bash, I think my answer is near to be the quicker way to do the job. Using bash resolver is very quick and running a `perl` script or `find | sed` implie a fork (or two) who would take lot more time and resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a *bug*. From man page:

```
BUGS
   Tree  does not prune "empty" directories when the -P and -I options are
   used.  Tree prints directories as it comes to them, so  cannot  accumu‐
   late  information  on files and directories beneath the directory it is
   printing.
```

... at all, `-d` switch ask to **not** print files:

```
    -d     List directories only.
```

So if you WANT use this, you could:

```
tree tstdir -P '*qm*' -L 1 | grep -B1 -- '-- .*qm'
|-- id1
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id1.0200.bin
--
|-- id165
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id165.0200.bin
|-- id166
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id166.0200.bin
--
|-- id17
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id17.0200.bin
--
|-- id18
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id18.0200.bin
--
|-- id2
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id2.0200.bin
```

At all, if you use `-L 1`,

```
   -L level
          Max display depth of the directory tree.
```

you could better use (in bash) this syntax:

```
cd tstdir
echo */*qm*
```

or

```
printf "%s\n" */*qm*
```

and if only dir is needed:

```
printf "%s\n" */*qm* | sed 's|/.*$||' | uniq
```

At all, you could do this very quickly if *pure bash*:

```
declare -A array;for file in  */*qm* ;do array[${file%/*}]='';done;echo "${!array[@]}"
```

This could be explained:

```
cd tstdir
declare -A array          # Declare associative array, (named ``array'')
for file in  */*qm* ;do   # For each *qm* in a subdirectory from there
    array[${file%/*}]=''  # Set a entry in array named as directory, containing nothing
  done
echo "${!array[@]}"         # print each entrys in array.
```

... if there is no file matching pattern, result would display `*`.
so for perfect the job, there left to do:

```
resultList=("${!array[@]}")
[ -d "$resultList" ] || unset $resultList
```

(This would be a lot quicker than

```
declare -A array
for file in  */*qm*; do
    [ "$file" == "*/*qm*" ] || array[${file%/*}]=''
  done
echo "${!array[@]}"
```

)

Answer (score 1):

You could use my [arbo command](https://github.com/g2p/arbo). Install with:

```
ln -s "$PWD"/arbo.py ~/bin/arbo
```

Now you can do:

```
find tstdir -maxdepth 1 -iname '*qm*' |arbo --color
```

The output looks something like this, with the same colors as ls:

```
git arbo
bedup
├─ __init__.py
├─ __main__.py
├─ platform/__init__.py
├─ termupdates.py
├─ test_bedup.py
└─ tracking.py
setup.py
tox.ini
```

Comment: I've added some output. ~+ was bash-specific.

Comment: ~+ is the same as "$PWD". The bash manpage gives you a few more expansions like that.

Comment: Yes you need Python 3. No, I won't give you a screenshot, you're asking for too much hand-holding.

Comment: I'm not asking for my benefit, it makes your answer stronger for others who may be considering trying your software out. Try not to make judgments of others!