# Tool to add hierarchical structure to output, similar to tree

Tags: shell-script, tree

Is there a tool that is similar to `tree` which could be used in conjunction with `echo`?

I want to easily prepend hierarchical structure to output.

I know I could write it, but if a solution ("do one thing well") already exists, I would much rather use that.

example `ptree`:
[image]

example `tree`:
[image]

Comment: In a generic way (to be used as a filter)? How would the tool know about that hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

There is no criteria about output classification, e.g. this tree output is from a previous download with wget

`results
├── 1
│   └── 2014
│       ├── 2
│       │   ├── 0
│       │   │   ├── st0
│       │   │   └── stout
│       │   └── 1
│       │       ├── st1
│       │       └── strout`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/g2p/arbo seems to do what you (might) want. The description on github states:

> Display a list of paths as a tree. Reads from stdin and also supports pre-defined modes for common VCSes, such as git.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it myself.

Note: I read about it in [Can the UNIX command tree display only directories matching a pattern?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61637/can-the-unix-command-tree-display-only-directories-matching-a-pattern)